# CentOS 7 w/Gnome hangs on boot after Nvidia driver installation?

Tags: centos7, x11, gnome, nvidia

there is a lot of information available on these topics separately, but I haven't been able to find an answer to what I feel is a really common situation.

I have 2 Nvidia GTX 1080s in a server with CentOS 7 and Gnome desktop.  The GPUs are going to be used exclusively for CUDA calculation, **not video output**.

See screenshot of Kernel loading screen.

[image: Load screen of GUI after Nvidia driver installation]

My xorg.conf looks like this:

```
[root@0cc47a8a1a10 ~]# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 367.44  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Wed Aug 17 22:54:35 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

[root@0cc47a8a1a10 ~]#
```

Here's the last part of /var/log/Xorg.5.log:

```
[    37.157] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    37.157] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    37.157] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    37.157] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    37.157] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fd419fc1020
[    37.157] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    37.157]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    37.157]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[    37.157]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    37.157]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    37.157] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    37.157] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card2)
[    37.157] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    37.157] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card3)
[    37.157] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card4)
[    37.165] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 10de:1b80:10de:119e rev 161, Mem @ 0xcf000000/16777216, 0x383fe0000000/268435456, 0x383ff0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00006000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    37.165] (--) PCI: (0:3:0:0) 10de:1b80:10de:119e rev 161, Mem @ 0xcd000000/16777216, 0x383fc0000000/268435456, 0x383fd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00005000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    37.165] (--) PCI:*(0:6:0:0) 1a03:2000:15d9:0852 rev 48, Mem @ 0xcb000000/16777216, 0xcc000000/131072, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    37.165] (--) PCI: (0:131:0:0) 10de:1b80:10de:119e rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0x387fe0000000/268435456, 0x387ff0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000d000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    37.165] (--) PCI: (0:132:0:0) 10de:1b80:10de:119e rev 161, Mem @ 0xf8000000/16777216, 0x387fc0000000/268435456, 0x387fd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000c000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    37.165] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    37.165] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    37.171] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    37.171]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    37.171]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    37.171] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  367.44  Wed Aug 17 21:50:26 PDT 2016
[    37.171] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    37.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    37.171] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    37.171]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    37.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.171] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  367.44  Wed Aug 17 21:28:13 PDT 2016
[    37.171] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    37.171] (++) using VT number 1

[    37.171] (EE) No devices detected.
[    37.171] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    37.171] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    37.171] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    37.171] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.5.log" for additional information.
[    37.171] (EE)
```

Comment: Plug in a monitor, or a dummy plug.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, there is a monitor plugged in to the on-board video controller, which is what we want.  Are you suggesting that the only way to do this is to use the Nvidia GPUs as video output?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can also use a dummy plug. Search the web for "DVI dummy plug" and go shopping.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt @MichaelHampton, I got things figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the Nvidia driver installer clobbers some files involving libglx.so.  I don't know what files exactly, and copying the original libglx.so over the one Nvidia sticks there didn't bring things back either.

Using the "**--no-opengl-files**" installation flag, **and** selecting "No" when prompted to overwrite the xconfig during installation resolved this issue.

In more detail, the steps were:

- Install CentOS 7 with Gnome desktop
- After boot:

  - yum -y update
  - yum -y install kernel-devel epel-release
  - yum -y install dkms gcc gcc-g++
  - Reboot (to get to new kernel)
- After boot:

  - sh latest_nvidia_driver.run --no-opengl-files
  - Select "no" when prompted for xconfig overwrite
  - systemctl set-default graphical.target (if your default run level is not already graphical)
  - Reboot